# How to accept all request types with a controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want my controller to accept all types of requests. For example:

```
{id}/stores
```

But it's working using:

```
{id}/stores.htm
```

My mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: Change your url pattern...

Comment: how will i change that pattern

Comment: Use an IDE or a text editor, erase the previous pattern and write a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your url pattern to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

It will handle all types of requests.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but the user might not want it.  Ought to be sure.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with server. Can you please try again after restarting the server?